# Prevent Papertrail's changeset from triggering N+1 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, paper-trail-gem

I have setup the Papertrail gem to track changes to my notes table. I want to show all the "updates" made to a note. I am doing this by:

`Annotation.last.versions.each { |v| v.changeset }`

This works, but is making unnecessary queries back to the Note table.

If a Note has N versions, then v.changeset does N queries to the Note table to get the same note. I assume this is because I have setup my relationship incorrectly. My set up is below.

```rb
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail(versions: { class_name: 'NoteVersion' })

End
```

```rb
class NoteVersion < PaperTrail::Version

  belongs_to(:note, foreign_key: :item_id, inverse_of: :versions)

End
```

My versions table has the tables: `item_type`, `item_id`, `object`, `object_changes` and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it always seems to happen you discover the answer just after posting!

It was my rails knowledge and how to setup polymorphic associations that was letting me down.

I could have changed the Version class to the below to correctly load the association.

```rb
class NoteVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  belongs_to(:item, polymorphic: true, optional: true, inverse_of: versions)
end
```

Or what I ended up doing was including the papertrail version concern which already has this logic built in.

```rb
class NoteVersion < PaperTrail::Version

  include(PaperTrail::VersionConcern)

end
```

Hopefully that will help someone else